# can any one tell what i2d_X509_SIG() function do..?

Tags: openssl

i am using openssl 0.9.8g. inside RSA_verify() function decrypoted data is given to the d21_X509_SIG function. what does this function do and why we are doing this step while signing and verifying the signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature is actually *not* just for the hash (e.g. SHA-256), but for a data structure containing the hash plus some metadata (which hashing algorithm, some parameters and the hash length).

That's why after decrypting, the data is decoded into a X509_SIG object and the actual comparison against the reference only performed on `sig->digest->data`.